# Is it wrong to validate passwords using mongoose middlewares?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

So right now I am using the validator package for email validation

```
const validator = require('validator');

email: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'User must have a email'],
    unique: true,
    lowercase: true, //transform to lowercase
    validate: [validator.isEmail, 'Please provide a valid email']
  }
```

So I found this function looking through Stack overflow:

```
var validateEmail = function(email) {
    var re = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
    return re.test(email)
};

var EmailSchema = new Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        lowercase: true,
        unique: true,
        required: 'Email address is required',
        validate: [validateEmail, 'Please fill a valid email address'],
        match: [/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/, 'Please fill a valid email address']
    }
});
```

So I was wondering, how can I use it or use something similar to run as a mongoose middleware? and, does it makes sense to use it as a middleware?

example:

```
userSchema.pre('save'....)
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically I think using schema validation makes more sense and is **easier to maintain** for sure.

**Using middleware for validation:**

I have tried it before and I have to say it's pretty hard to get it right. If you define the middleware as a `pre.('save', ...)` (and this is the correct one to use) one as you mentioned, there are some cases when you are trying to update the doc, the middleware does not get executed, and you have to take care of those situations in separate tasks which are hard to maintain and you can't be sure that they did work or you didn't miss any cases. [More on this topic](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#notes)